# Flutter Provider, update StreamProvider when his parameter changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I've been developing this Flutter application in which one widget needs to read a list of Objects from firestore database.

To do so, I've a model for the specific Object (which is called Polizza).

I've a class called DatabaseService which contains the methods for getting the Streams.

In this case, this is the method I use to query the DB and get a stream:

```
Stream<List<Polizza>> streamPolizze({String id, String filter = ''}) {
    var ref = _db
        .collection('polizze')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('elenco')
        .orderBy('indice');

    if (filter.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> list = filter.split(' ').map((e) => e.toUpperCase());
      ref = ref.where('indice', arrayContainsAny: list);
    }

    return ref.limit(10).snapshots().map(
        (list) => list.docs.map((doc) => Polizza.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }
```

In the parent widget I was using a StreamProvider to enable his children to access the List of Polizza:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    var filter = Provider.of<FilterPolizze>(context);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => DatabaseService().streamPolizze(id: user.uid))
      ],
      child: ...
    );
  }
```

It worked.

But now I want to apply a filter to the query.
For doing so I've built a simple TextField widget, which is able to provide me the filter value throught a ChangeNotifierProvider.
This works fine, in fact I can read the filter and his updates from Provider.of(context).
FilterPolizze is the Object type I've built for the filter.

I've tried to update the StreamProvider like that:

```
StreamProvider(create: (BuildContext context) => DatabaseService().streamPolizze(id: user.uid, filter: filter.value))
```

But it seems like it doesn't rebuild.

How can I notify the StreamProvider to rebuild itself if one of his parameters change?

Comment: I don't think it would work for you, I would assign the recieved data to the some changenotifireprovider's value and filter it before rebuilding the some page or widget.
assigning would take place inside the stream, and filtering will happen before rebuilding the page or widget with changeNotifier.

Comment: Are you referring to Pieter van Loon answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the `SteamProvider` a `Key` which you change when the filter changes.
So for instance use a key with the value `'polizze${filter.value}'`

Comment: It is not clear to me why to add a key. If this changes, will it trigger the widget to update?

Comment: The key will signal to flutter thats you have given it a different streamprovider than it had before, so the widget will be built from scratch removing any previous state and thus should call the create again

Comment: It worked, but since the widget is reconstructed, it causes a lot of other problems. For example I lose the focus on the filter textfield and the filter itself get cleaned.

Comment: I solved it by wrapping the part I was interested in rebuilding inside a new widget, and moving the provider to that new widget. This way I only rebuild what is necessary.
I'll consider marking your answer as the solution.